# How to style disabled (and also checked) radio button using Bootstrap v3.4.1?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

I'm using **Bootstrap v3.4.1** radio button on dark theme and it's almost unrecognizable which one is checked when radio button or its form is disabled. On light theme is quite good.
Is there any chance to style disabled radio button? Is there any available property for changing as color, background etc?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a new line into the css which targets the button when it's disabled.

.btn:disabled { // Your style }

Comment: I've tried that, but there is no changes at all. Radio button is still in disabled grey color.

Answer (score 0):

You can try for disabled radios this:

```
    input[type='radio']:disabled {
     transform: scale(2.5);
    }
```